# local cohomology and radical of ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $R$ be commutative ring with identity, $M$ an $R$-module, and $I$ an ideal of $R$ . One defines $I$-torsion functor $Γ_I$  as: $\Gamma_I(M)=\bigcup_{n\in N} (0:_MI^n).$ When $R$ is Noetherian, it's known that $$\color{brown}{\Gamma_I(M)=\Gamma_{\sqrt I}(M)}.$$ 
When $R$ is non-Noetherian,  there is a [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315574/local-cohomology-and-radical-of-ideal) for it.

> What conditions can be posed on ring (or ideals), to have $\Gamma_I(R)=\Gamma_{\sqrt I}(R),$ for **every** ideal of $R$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is studied in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40306-013-0020-5) (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0610.pdf) for the arxiv version), mainly in case the supporting ideal is a monomial ideal in a polynomial ring.

**ADDENDUM (2017):** A completely different condition that ensures $\Gamma_I=\Gamma_{\sqrt{I}}$ for every ideal $I$ is that $R$ is absolutely flat.

Comment: Thank you @Fred. Does the article suggest conditions that the equality holds for **every** ideal of $R$?

Comment: No, not beside the obvious ones (cf. Corollary 1.3 and the following remark).